# Cells show number as text despite number format

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, cell-format

I have a range of cells I apply a number format to using the EPPlus Excel library for .NET. I apply the format as follows:

```
ws.Cells[$"D{startAt + 3}:E{endAt - 1}"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,##0.00";
```

I can see that the cells have the correct format by right-clicking a cell and choosing `Cell Format`. This shows `number` with a format of `-1,234.10`. If I apply the formula `=CELL("format")` to one of these cells, the result is `,2`, which according to [this MS doc](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/cell-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf), the format is `#,##0.00`, which is correct.

Yet these cells still show left aligned with a warning triangle that the cell is a number stored as text. Why is this, the cell format is clearly number?

Comment: *Why is this, the cell format is clearly number?* No. You set the format which must be applied only if a datatype in a cell is Number. But your datatype is not altered by setting NumberFormat, it remains Text. Try to reassign the value (simple `cell.value=cell.value`) or to replace cell value from `-1234.1` to `=-1234.1`. PS. I do not know how to alter cell datatype - if enable macrorecorder and then fix the datatype in a cell using context error fix, then the recorded macro is empty. The same if set new cell format - no statements relative to this in the macro.

Comment: @Akina Thank you, I did something like what you say and it worked. Why not answer the question and I will accept?

Comment: It's more of a dance with a tambourine than a real solution.